# C# project not running on a Linux System

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio, .net-core

I developed a C# project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 in .Net Core Environment. I works properly on my Windows 7 system. I want to run this project on a Linux system. I havent worked on Visual Studio code in Linux before. I copied the debug folder of my project on the linux system. But it is not running .
Any suggestions on how to approach the problem to run the project on Linux.

Comment: go through this https://blog.todotnet.com/2017/07/publishing-and-running-your-asp-net-core-project-on-linux/

Comment: Well you'll probably need to rebuild it _on_ Linux...

Comment: The problem is that one of the dlls is not supported in Linux. I keep getting the error "an assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest was not found" .

Comment: Well, then you have your answer (probably). If the DLL cannot run on Linux then you can't put it into an application you expect to run on Linux unless there is a suitable replacement for that DLL. What exactly is the DLL in question?

Comment: You should read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/), deploying to another machine is not as simple as copying the built files. If that doesn't help, you will need to include much more details about what you're doing and how it's failing.